# Как вместо обычной строки подставлять в код вместо нее "обрезанную" с помощью substring() строку

Tags: javascript

> Всем привет, есть название книги (если длинное, то переносится на 2
>   строчку). Так вот, до этого обрезал с помощью text-overflow, но это
>   свойство не работает 2 строчками текста. JS только недавно начал учить
>   и захотелось обрезать эту строчку при помощи substring(). Обрезать получилось, но как теперь вместо "целой" подставить "обрезанную".

вот мой код))

```
const bookName = document.querySelector('.popular__slider-descr-text').textContent;

function cutString(str) {

if (str.length >= 10) {
    bookName.substring(0, 10);
  }
}
cutString(bookName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function cutString(str) {
  if (str.length >= 10) {
    str = str.substring(0, 10);
  }
  return str;
}

const bookName = document.querySelector('.popular__slider-descr-text');
bookName.textContent = cutString(bookName.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="popular__slider-descr-text">
The walrus and the carpenter walked for a mile or so
</div>
```

Comment: выдает ошибку: Сannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров Вы неаккуратно скопировали мой код.

Comment: действительно, извините) а ошибка появилась из-за того, что переменная bookName была определена до функции?

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров Нет, ошибка возникла из-за чего-то еще.

Comment: всё, я просто не положил str.substring(0, 10) в переменную, спасибо вам!)

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Можно просто `function cutString(str) { return str.substring(0, 10); }` без проверок)